# PHP GET parameters - Make parameters with and without space mean same

Tags: php, url-parameters

First of all, sorry if my title isn't so precise.

Is it possible, if yes, how, to make parameters "`city=Los%20Angeles`" and "`city=LosAngeles`" same? I have ads website with search by city, and problem is that some ads's city variables contain space (%20), and some don't. That is a problem when searching ads because searching **Los Angeles** won't show ads with city LosAngeles.

So 1st url needs to show ads from 1st and 2nd url 
1st url https://www.mywebsite.com/city-Los%20Angeles/listings.html 
2nd url https://www.mywebsite.com/city-LosAngeles/listings.html

If helps, I use smarty template engine.

Comment: post your search query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put your $_GET value into a parameter
2. Use urldecode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to convert URL encodings
3. Use str_replace http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to remove spaces $val = str_replace(" ", "", $yourVariable)

   $city = urldecode($_GET["city"]);

   $city = str_replace(" ", "", $city);

Answer (score 0):

If what i understand from your description is true, you want to delete empty space character from the parameter passed through.

If so, this might work for you

```
$param_city = str_replace("%20", "", $_POST['city']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to check it in PHP just do the following: 
`$str = $_GET['city'];
echo $str . " ";
echo trim($str,"Hed!");`
This will allow you to read it the same way in PHP.

Or you could do it in your HTACCESS file.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to standardize the variables once they are received. This is a good practice, anyway, as you will want to remove any potentially dangerous characters during the filtering process.

So, while this is a good option:

```
$city = str_replace('%20', '', $city);
```

If you know that you would be fine with only handling letters, and that it's fine being case insensitive, then perhaps you could do something like:

```
$city = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', strtolower($city));
```

This later option would also prevent any malicious characters that other parts of your code might not handle well. Also, assuming spelling is correct, that should mean that for each city, there would be exactly one possible string.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did it as [Dom C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5932020/dom-c) said and It's working, but I somehow forgot to post it.

Thank you all for your answers.